# Meteor collection2 type Object

Tags: meteor, meteor-collection2

I'm trying to create a field modifiedBy with type: Object (to Meteor users).

I see you can setup blackbox: true for a Custom Object, but if I want to setup to a specific Object say a Group (collection) field modifiedBy is the logged in user, any pointers/help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I see it, you have two options:

- Store user-ids there with `type: String`
- Denormalize it as you proposed

---

### Denormalize it as you proposed

To denormalize it you can do something like this inside your schema:

```
...
modifiedBy: {
  type: object
}

'modifiedBy._id': {
  type: String,
  autoValue: function () {
    return Meteor.userId()
  }
}

'modifiedBy.username': {
  type: String,
  autoValue: function () {
    return Meteor.user().username
  }
}
...
```

As you pointed out, you'd want to update these properties when they change:

*server-side*

```
Meteor.users.find().observe({
  changed: function (newDoc) {
    var updateThese = SomeCollection.find({'modifiedBy.username': {$eq: newDoc._id}})
    updateThese.forEach () {
      SomeCollection.update(updateThis._id, {$set: {name: newDoc.profile.name}})
    }
  }
})
```

---

### Store user-ids there with `type: String`

I'd recommend storing user-ids. It's cleaner but it doesn't perform as well as the other solution. Here's how you could do that:

```
...
modifiedBy: {
  type: String
}
...
```

You could also easily write a [`Custom Validator`](https://github.com/aldeed/meteor-simple-schema#custom-validation) for this. Now retrieving the Users is a bit more complicated. You could use a [transform function](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/mongo_collection) to get the user objects.

```
SomeCollection = new Mongo.Collection('SomeCollection', {
  transform: function (doc) {
    doc.modifiedBy = Meteor.users.findOne(doc.modifiedBy)
    return doc
  }
})
```

But there's a catch: "Transforms are not applied for the callbacks of observeChanges or to cursors returned from publish functions."

This means that to retrieve the doc reactively you'll have to write an abstraction:

```
getSome = (function getSomeClosure (query) {
  var allDep = new Tacker.Dependency
  var allChanged = allDep.changed.bind(allDep)
  SomeCollection.find(query).observe({
    added: allChanged,
    changed: allChanged,
    removed: allChanged
  })
  return function getSome () {
    allDep.depend()
    return SomeCollection.find(query).fetch()
  }
})
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. Should those autoValues be swapped?
How do I set the modifiedBy while saving the object, also will the username be updated when we update the user details? probably I'll use the profile.name instead of username?

Comment: Sorry about that, the should. The values will be normal string, so they wont be updated. This is why i prefer the first method. So I wrote some code to help you with that. Sorry it took so long..

Comment: Say there are 10K objects in my collections, does that run the transform function 10K times? Or can do something like don't run the transform if it is find (all) and RUN only when it is findOne??

Comment: Yeah it would. In that chase you'll probably want to denormalize, as you initially proposed.

Comment: In that case we need to update the modifiedBy.name when there is a change, nice.
How do I set the modifiedBy to save it?
is it like obj.modifiedBy = {_id: xxx, name: yyy} ??

Comment: I updated my answer. Could you update the question correspondingly.

Comment: I was asking about the modifiedBy (type: Object) field - how do I set while saving?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/81133/discussion-between-kriegslustig-and-user237865).